# Ошибка при создании поля класса

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Ошибка, при попытке создать поле в классе.

> Class properties must be methods. Expected '(' but instead saw '='.
> (E054)jshint(E054)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте код и сообщения об ошибках текстом.

Comment: Исправил.
Я думаю, что дело в jshint, но я не знаю, что там надо менять.

Comment: Тут вам ещё подскажут, надеюсь. Могу лишь допустить, что jshint, кажется, довольно древний линтер, и он просто может не поддерживать поля классов, которые не так давно были добавлены в язык.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо знать на какую версию EcmaScript вы пишите точно. Потом надо настроить эту версию в jshint.

в ES5 нельзя объявлять свойства класса вне конструктора, только внутри него. Поэтому такая запись некорректна.
В ES6 и выше - можно.

У вас два варианта:

- Если вы пишите под >=ES6, то в jshint указать:

  ```
  esversion: 6
  ```

  где вместо "6" - ваша версия. Самая простая конфигурация `.jshintrc` может быть такой:

  ```
  {
      "esversion": 6
  }
  ```
- Если пишите под <=ES5, то объявлять свойства только в конструкторе

---

все ключи jshint'а:  https://jshint.com/docs/options/